# How to return only one time nested object in dto using mapstruct

Tags: spring-boot, rest, dto, mapstruct

I have a dto that contains an instance of himself :

```
class Person{
  private int id;
  private Person parent;
}
```

my data :

```
list<Person> persons = new Arraylist<>();
Person one = new Person(1,null);
persons.add(one);
Person two = new Person(2,one);
persons.add(two);
Person three = new Persone(3,two);
persons.add(three);
```

when i return the dto the result is like this :

```
[
{id : 1, parent: null},
{id : 2, parent: {id : 1, parent: null}},
{id : 3, parent: {id : 2, parent: {id : 1, parent: null}}
]
```

what i want :

```
[
{id : 1, parent: null},
{id : 2, parent: {id : 1, parent: null}},
{id : 3, parent: {id : 2, parent: null}}
]
```

is there a way to do this using mapstruct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using @AfterMapping and delete manualy grandparents. I don't know if it is the best solution :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PersonMapper{

    PersonDto personToPersonDTO(Person person);

    @AfterMapping
    default void deleteGrandParents(@MappingTarget PersonDto person) {
        if (person.getParent() != null) {
            person.getParent().setParent(null);
        }
    }
}
```